# Sound handler using Clip and AudioInputstream keeps audio in RAM

Tags: java, audio

A sound handler I have developed for my game handles playing musing and sound effects. In theory there should be one voice for each sfx and music, and each should only be able to play one track at a time.

However, whilst monitoring the resources used the RAM used exponentially increases when skipping through tracks, all the way to the argument limit of 8Gb - meaning that it loads tracks into memory again each time it is played and is never dumped.

Whilst debugging this, I placed an unhealthy amount of .Drains and .Flushes on the Clips in my class, and resetting the AudioInputStream to null, experimenting with no effect.

On a side note, when skipping through tracks quickly, an occasional phantom voices will appear, continuing to play in the background uncontrollably of the controlled Music voice - I feel this are likely closely related.

Below is the entire class, including all positions which .Drain etc were used during debugging. Song skipping starts from `NextTrack()` or `PrevTrack()`, both give the same result.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;

public class SoundHandler {
    private static Clip sfx = null, Music = null;
    public static boolean MusicEnabled = true;
    private static int STIndex = 0;
    private static final int TrackCount = 41;
    private static AudioInputStream audioInputStream;    

        //Channel true = sfx, else music
        private static void PlayFile(String filename, boolean Chanel){
            try {
                   audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename)));

                if (Chanel) {
                    try {sfx.stop(); sfx.drain();}catch (Exception e) {}
                    sfx = AudioSystem.getClip();
                    sfx.open(audioInputStream);
                    sfx.start();
                } else {
                    if (!MusicEnabled) {return;}
                    try {Music.stop(); Music.drain();}catch (Exception e) {}
                    Music = AudioSystem.getClip();
                    Music.open(audioInputStream);
                    Music.start();                  
                }




            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        //Music Handler for external
        private static void PlayTrack() {
            String Location = String.valueOf(Game.ResourcePath + "/Audio/Runtime/ST" + STIndex + ".wav");    
            PlayFile(Location, false);
        }

        public static void SFX(String Effect) {
            String Location = String.valueOf(Game.ResourcePath + "/Audio/Runtime/" + Effect + ".wav");
            PlayFile(Location, true);
        }


        public static void NextTrack() {
            if (STIndex >= TrackCount) {STIndex = 0;} else {STIndex++;}
            Music.stop();
            Music.drain();
            Music.flush();          
            try {audioInputStream.close();} catch (IOException e) {}
            audioInputStream = null;
            PlayTrack();
        }

        public static void PrevTrack() {
            if (STIndex <= 0) {STIndex = TrackCount;} else {STIndex--;}
            Music.stop();
            Music.drain();
            Music.flush();          
            try {audioInputStream.close();} catch (IOException e) {}
            audioInputStream = null;
            PlayTrack();
        }

        public static void StartMusic () {
            MusicEnabled = true;
            STIndex = 0;
            String Location = String.valueOf(Game.ResourcePath + "/Audio/Runtime/ST" + STIndex + ".wav");
            PlayFile(Location, false);
        }

        public static void PlayIndex(int index) {
            MusicEnabled = true;
            STIndex = 0;
            String Location = String.valueOf(Game.ResourcePath + "/Audio/Runtime/ST" + index + ".wav");
            PlayFile(Location, false);
        }

        public static void PlayStop() {
            MusicEnabled = !MusicEnabled;
            if (MusicEnabled) {
                StartMusic();
            } else {
                try {Music.stop(); Music.drain(); Music.flush();}catch (Exception e) {}
            }}

        public static void Tick() {
            try {if ((!Music.isActive()) && MusicEnabled){NextTrack();}} catch (Exception e) {}
            if (!MusicEnabled) {
                try {if (!Music.isActive()){Music.stop(); Music.drain();}} catch (Exception e) {}
            }}

        public static int getST() {
            return STIndex;
        }


}
```

Comment: When you’re done with a Clip, close it.  When you’re done with an AudioInputStream, close it.

Comment: Whilst closing the clip has reduced it's memory usage it still increases with each track - just not quite as much now, and the generation of phantom voices still occurs